# generating function for Bell polynomial

Tags: stirling-numbers, bell-numbers

How it can be proved that :
$$\sum_{n=0}^{ ∞}B_{n}\left(x\right)\frac{t^{n}}{n!}=e^{x\left(e^{t}-1\right)}$$

Where $B_n$ is the $n^{th}$ complete Bell polynomial.
I know that $$\sum_{n=k}^{∞ }S\left(n,k\right)\frac{t^{n}}{n!}=\frac{1}{k!}\left(e^{t}-1\right)^{k}$$

where $S\left(n,k\right)$ is Stirling number of the second kind,e.g. the number of way to partition a say 
with $n$ distinguished objects into $k$ nonempty partitions, but is it useful to prove my question?

Comment: What's your definition of $B_n(x)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bell polynomials are defined by 
\begin{eqnarray*}
B_n(x)= \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \brace k} x^k.   \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Thus we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} B_n(x) \frac{t^n}{n!} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \brace k} x^k \frac{t^n}{n!}.   \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now inverting the order of the plums & using the formula stated in the question 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \brace k} x^k \frac{t^n}{n!} &=&  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} {n \brace k}  \frac{t^n}{n!} x^k \\
&=&  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(e^{t}-1)^k}{k!} x^k \\
&=& \color{red}{ \operatorname{exp}(x(e^t-1)) }.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thank you so much,can you just explain about the index changing $n=k$?

Comment: For each value of $n=0,1,\cdots \infty$, $k$ will take the values $0 \leq k \leq n$. This is the same as $k$ taking an value from $0$ to $\infty$ but now we need $ n \geq k$, in other words for $k=0,1,\cdots \infty$, $n$ will range over $k,k+1, \cdots$.

Comment: thank you for you consideration.

Comment: (1) F. Qi, Some inequalities and an application of exponential polynomials, Math. Inequal. Appl. 23 (2020), no. 1, 123--135; available online at https://doi.org/10.7153/mia-2020-23-10.
(2) F. Qi, D.-W. Niu, D. Lim, and B.-N. Guo, Some properties and an application of multivariate exponential polynomials, Math. Methods Appl. Sci. 43 (2020), no. 6, 2967--2983; available online at https://doi.org/10.1002/mma.6095.
(3) F. Qi, Some inequalities for the Bell numbers, Proc. Indian Academy Sci. Math. Sci. 127 (2017), no. 4, 551--564; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s12044-017-0355-2.